# Using the networks extension, how to identify network nodes in the output?

Tags: netlogo

When outputting a network using `nw:save-matrix file-name`, is there a way to identify individual nodes, or at least identify their breed, something like including a header with breed information at the top of each column? If not, is there any other easy way to output this information and the network?